# Windows Workflow Correlation with Workflow Services

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a locally hosted Windows Workflow (4.5) site running on App Fabric. The Workflow is very simple, at present, consisting of two workflow services the first saves correlation based on  Guid (DB Generated) and the second just receives the same object with the guid in, the second is set to retrieve the guid for correlation.

I have a problem with the second part of my workflow, apparently, not being called. The calling site returns with this error:

```
The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

Now, what is puzzling is if I intentionally put in a correlation id (guid) that is not correct, then Workflow returns saying there is no matching process. When there is correct correlation identifier it times-out.

Correlation keys are the same at both points, it is in idle state in IIS and App Fabric. App Fabric has the above error in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems a problem of permissions and/or configuration. Have you enabled net.pipe protocol on IIS bindings? Are AppFabric windows services running with accounts with AS_Admin permissions? Turn WCF tracing on. It will surely give you additional debugging info.

Comment: I can see in AppFabric it is waiting for the new WCF call so it is going into the persistence db correctly. Its weird. The correlation key is part of another object being passed in. An incorrect key fails, but the correct one times out. I have removed all other logic apart from the receive send on the second part.

Comment: Sorry to answer your question, net.pipe is enabled. Having a problem getting logging to write anything out. The error in App Fabric is a timeout.

Comment: I've sent this to Microsoft as I can get another workflow working which does the same thing and can't see the difference.